# HERE SDK Android: PositioningManager not working with NETWORK_PROVIDER in 3.8 or 3.9

Tags: android, here-api

I'm working on updating an existing product using here-sdk from version 3.7 to 3.8 / 3.9

It has hardware gps on board available via android `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`, but also receives location information from an external device which is injected via location mock as the network provider:

```
this.locationManager.addTestProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
            false, false, false, false, true, true, true,
            Criteria.POWER_LOW, Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
this.locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, true);
this.locationManager.setTestProviderStatus(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 
            LocationProvider.AVAILABLE, null, System.currentTimeMillis());
```

This external data is used primarily whenever gps is not available, eg. during startup.

PositioningManager is started with: `PositioningManager.getInstance().start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK);`

Other places in the codebase have `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, ...)` -> `onLocationChanged(Location location)` handlers that fire on each new mocked location, plus other handlers listening to `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` which work for updates from hardware gps.

There are also `PositioningManager` `onPositionFixChanged()` listeners which fire for these same coordinates from both providers.

On HERE SDK 3.7 this all works perfectly.

Once I upgrade HERE SDK to 3.8 however the network provider updates stop working.
The map display no longer updates and the `onPositionFixChanged()` listeners no longer fires for mock network updates. GPS updates work fine however.

The LocationManager `onLocationChanged` listeners still work for network, but not the PositioningManager callbacks.

If I change the mock provider to override `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` instead of network, `onPositionFixChanged()` and the map updates correctly, but then the real gps coordinates are lost.

SDK 3.9 behaves the same.

Even changing Positioning Manager startup to not use gps, only network does not work, I get no updates from either provider then.

Switching back to 3.7 aar file makes it all work again (with no other code changes)

In case it helps, the device is running Android 5.1.1

Thanks!

Comment: Not heard of such an issue within the SKD release before. I cannot reproduce it here locally.
Please provide some sample code that helps reproducing this issue, maybe there is something wrong with implementation side.

Comment: I don't have a clean reproduction case unfortunately, I'm taken on an open source codebase for the Navdy HUD which is where I'm having these issues.

Comment: PositioningManager configuration: https://gitlab.com/alelec/navdy/navdy-display-Hud-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/navdy/hud/app/maps/here/HereMapsManager.java#L200

Comment: TestProvider init: https://gitlab.com/alelec/navdy/navdy-display-Hud-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/navdy/hud/app/device/gps/GpsManager.java#L652

Comment: TestProvider Usage: https://gitlab.com/alelec/navdy/navdy-display-Hud-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/navdy/hud/app/device/gps/GpsManager.java#L735

Comment: onPositionUpdated (works on 3.7, not 3.8): https://gitlab.com/alelec/navdy/navdy-display-Hud-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/navdy/hud/app/maps/here/HereMapsManager$3.java

Comment: onLocationChanged (registered for network, works on all versions): https://gitlab.com/alelec/navdy/navdy-display-Hud-java/blob/gps_startup/src/main/java/com/navdy/hud/app/maps/here/HereLocationFixManager.java#L139

Comment: Sorry the code is very convoluted, messy and hard to follow. It's taken me a month (out of office hours) to narrow down this issue to this point. On a related note, is there any other way to inject positions into PositioningManager other than the PositionSimulator which needs to take them from a log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a closer look into this topic and the root cause is here a change with the following background:

Within the 3.7 SDK we experienced an issue with the Tunnel extrapolation broken by "bad" network positions - In a simple test app a tunnel extrapolation was interrupted by a network position claim to be 24M accurate but likely was not. This is just one example but something which definitely should not happen. Within changes introduced ion 3.8 one we considered that the Android HERE We Go did not have this problem because it only uses LocationMethod.GPS during navigation and LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK at all other times. The implementation of the same behavior means generally better navigation in tunnels is underway.

So the usage of an external device to get the location will not working starting from 3.8 and for now it is considered as expected behavior. 
    On the other hand it is not needed any longer as the SDK supports a much better tracking.

Comment: Thanks so much for that, that's really helpful! Was this noted anywhere in the release note? I couldn't see anything like this in the ones I looked at.

Comment: Actually I was just starting to test a change on my end that had seemed to work around my issue, I started injecting the mock locations into the same network provider, but tagging the Location objects themselves as POSITION_GPS. They then seem to get picked up and used by HERE. This sounds like it's fairly consistent with your details. I can see that your changes would be useful in the majority of use cases, mine is very non-standard though so I'm fine with our workaround for times before the gps has locked in.